# How do i work with a potentially nullable field in prisma ORM and MongoDB that references the id of another model?

Tags: database, mongodb, forms, orm, prisma

```
model Product{
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name String
  subcategoryId String @db.ObjectId
  subcategory Subcategory? @relation(fields: [subcategoryId],references: [id])
  categoryId String @db.ObjectId
  category Category @relation(fields: [categoryId],references: [id])
  price Float
  brand String
  isFeatured Boolean @default(false)
  isArchived Boolean @default(false)
  sizeId String[] @db.ObjectId
  size Size[] @relation(fields: [sizeId], references: [id])
  reviews Review[]
  images ProductImage[]
  orderItem OrderItem[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt


  @@index([categoryId])
  @@index([sizeId])
   
}

model Subcategory{
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  billboardId String @db.ObjectId
  billboard BillBoard @relation(fields: [billboardId],references: [id])
  categoryId String @db.ObjectId
  category Category @relation(fields: [categoryId],references: [id])
  product Product[]
  name String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

}

export const ProductSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1),
  categoryId: z.string().min(1),
  subcategoryId: z.string().optional(),
  sizeId: z.array(z.string()),
  price: z.coerce.number().min(1),
  brand: z.string().min(1),
  isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
  isArchived: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
  images: z.array(ProductImageSchema),
});

import { currentRole } from "@/hooks/use-current-role-server";
import { currentUser } from "@/hooks/use-current-user-server";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { UserRole } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const user = await currentUser();
    const role = await currentRole();
    const userId = user?.id;
    const body = await req.json();
    const {
      name,
      categoryId,
      subcategoryId,
      sizeId,
      price,
      brand,
      isArchived,
      isFeatured,
      images,
    } = body;

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }
    if (role !== UserRole.ADMIN) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }
    if (!name) {
      return new NextResponse("Name is required", { status: 400 });
    }
    if (!categoryId) {
      return new NextResponse("Category is required", { status: 400 });
    }

    if (!sizeId || sizeId.length === 0) {
      return new NextResponse("Size is required", { status: 400 });
    }

    if (!price) {
      return new NextResponse("Size is required", { status: 400 });
    }

    const product = await db.product.create({
      data: {
        name,
        categoryId,
        subcategoryId: subcategoryId || null,
        sizeId,
        price,
        brand,
        isArchived,
        isFeatured,
        images,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(product);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[PRODUCT_POST]", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

If you look at my Prisma schema you will notice that i want the subcategories to be optional hence the ? after it. If you look a the Zod schema too you will notice i also have z.string.optional() but when i try to submit the form i get strange errors when the subcategoryId is not selected but it works when it is so i know the issue is from subcategory not being selected i need a solution because i want subcategories to be optional

The error i normally get

```
Invalid `prisma.product.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    name: "Sneakers",
    categoryId: "6604bc28973d8ff95e7b4d44",
    subcategoryId: null,
    sizeId: [
      "6600a1124992965a353051c2",
      "6604b694973d8ff95e7b4d3a"
    ],
    price: 30300,
    brand: "Brand",
    isArchived: false,
    isFeatured: true,
    images: [
      {
        colorId: "65f9a296f87aafb1836df2d5",
        imageURLs: [
          "https://res.cloudinary.com/dezuiqfsq/image/upload/v1711638173/ckrn1qi0bsdtfu8kn0zf.jpg"
        ]
      }
    ],
+   category: {
+     create: CategoryCreateWithoutProductInput | CategoryUncheckedCreateWithoutProductInput,
+     connectOrCreate: CategoryCreateOrConnectWithoutProductInput,
+     connect: CategoryWhereUniqueInput
+   }
  }
}

Argument `category` is missing.
    at Cn (C:\Users\brian\Documents\Portfolio\cms\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:116:5888)
    at _n.handleRequestError (C:\Users\brian\Documents\Portfolio\cms\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6510)
    at _n.handleAndLogRequestError 
..................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that `subcategory` on the `Product` model is nullable, but `subcategoryId` (the field right above it) is not. As far as Prisma is concerned, you **need** to specify the `subcategoryId` field to create a new `Product`. Just make `subcategoryId` nullable and you should be good to go!

```
subcategoryId String? @db.ObjectId
```